# Approach to find eigen values and eigen vectors of very large degrees of freedom system

Tags: python, math

I want to do a modal analysis of large degrees of freedom system in python. I have mass(M) and stiffness(K) matrices. I have used

```
import scipy.linalg as la
evals, evecs = la.eig(K,M)
```

but results are not matching with analytical ones. I have also used

```
import scipy.sparse.linalg as la
import scipy.sparse as sp`
kk=sp.csr_matrix(K)
mm = sp.csr_matrix(M)
evals, evecs= la.eigsh(A=kk, k=6, M=mm,sigma=0)
frequencies = np.sqrt(evals)/(2*np.pi)
print ("Natural Frequencies : \n", frequencies)
```

but this gives only first few natural frequencies.
Can anybody please suggest possible approach to find eigen values and eigen vectors of very large degrees of freedom system?

Comment: How exactly do the Eigenvalues computed from scipy.linalg.eig not match the analytical ones? Maybe they have been normalized?

Comment: Givens or Householder methods are typically used.